# How to write a while loop until two outputs are the same ? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to write a program that uses Newton's method to get an number's square root. Basically it needs to keep iterating until two consecutive values are the same. I think I am nearly there I just don't know what to put in the last part of the while loop.

```
def SquareRoot(X):

    root = X
    print(X)
       
    while root != DONT KNOW :
        root = 0.5*(root+(X/root))
        print(root)
        
SquareRoot(64)
```

Comment: You can check `if root * root == X` but be aware of floating point issues. In that case, check that the difference is less than some acceptable value. `if abs(root * root - X) < 0.0001` for example.

Comment: Sorry, should be `>` for a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
def SquareRoot(X):

    root = X
    print(X)
   
    while root**2 != X :
        root = 0.5*(root+(X/root))
        print(root)
SquareRoot(64)
```

but you can't do it for irrationals,

but to make it work you could round:

```
>>> def SquareRoot(X):
...     root = X
...     print(X)
...     while round(root**2,12) != X :
...         root = 0.5*(root+(X/root))
...         print(round(root,12))
...     return round(root,12)
...
>>> SquareRoot(2)
2
1.5
1.416666666667
1.414215686275
1.414213562375
1.414213562373
1.414213562373
```

Comment: Presumably, since you're answering Python questions, you understand that indentation affects the meaning of Python code. Perhaps you would like to [edit] your code and correct the indentation so that your code is usable and makes sense.

Comment: It worked thank you ! I am extremely new to coding and sometimes it takes me a while to figure out obvious stuff like this. Thanks !

Comment: @khelwood it does work ? The identation is fine. But thank you.

Comment: Try your code with `SquareRoot(2)`. Please see my earlier comment.

Comment: yea, if it would result in a irrational number, it would continue forever

Comment: i edited the code, see my answer edited

Comment: You would be better off with something like @JohnnyMopp's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71037145/how-to-write-a-while-loop-until-two-outputs-are-the-same-python/71037194?noredirect=1#comment125577238_71037145). Try your revised version with `SquareRoot(math.pi)`